# JS - Map/Array choice when both can do the same task

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is probably more of an opinion based question. But recently on a project I have seen that [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is always used over [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

My question is when would you ever use an `array` over a `Map`?

*Note* I mean in cases where an array would work as well as a Map.

i.e. storing data, checking it exists, and deleting it.

example here:

```js
// Array
const teams = [];

if (teams.includes(team.id)) {
  return;
}

teams.push(team.id);

// do stuff

teams = teams.filter(
  (id) => id !== team.id
);


// Map
const teams = new Map();

if (teams.has(team.id)) {
  return;
}

teams.set(team.id, team.id);
// do stuff

teams(team.id);
```

As I understand Map is more performant, you also get methods like `get`, `set`, `delete` which are useful.

If faced with the task above what would people use and why?

Comment: A Map is an ordered Object with keys and values. Arrays don't have keys, only indices. I would use a Map for dictionary lookups that need to be in order.

Comment: Accessing elements in `Array`  is constant time if done via `index`. However, accessing the way like above(`includes` etc..) will be linear time.

Comment: One criteria that I employ is, if there is too much access and index(numeric) is known, go for `array`, otherwise if `index` is not known... better would be `Map`. Access with `Maps`   is constant time, whether the index is numeric or not.

Comment: In case it is a List with simple datatypes (Number, String, Boolean), you would usually use Array.  Keeping an order is usually easier in Arrays than in Maps, as it has an index. A Map is preferable to an Array when you have key value pairs, e.g. person.id => person (Object). In your case, an Array would probably be better, since using an id as key AND value in a Map doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you want convenient methods like in Map, but just want to store simple data, you could rather use a Set.
Performance wise it really depends on what you are doing with your data.